# How to do redirection which has different domain in office 365 app

Tags: ms-office, office365, office365-apps, office-js

is there way to redirect different url which is belonged to different domain in office 365 app ?
here is sample manifest file and source and it says'***Refused to display 'https://google.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'***.'

```
<AppDomains>        
        <AppDomain>https://google.com</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>

Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {               
                window.location = "https://www.google.com";
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, Google is the one saying "don't load me in an iframe". See the [X-Frame-Options documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options). So it should work with some other site, just not one that's setting X-Frame-Options.

For scenarios like OAuth, you can do things via a [pop-up](http://simonjaeger.com/building-a-good-authentication-flow-in-an-office-add-in/) or using the new [dialog API](http://simonjaeger.com/lets-have-a-dialog-about-the-dialog-api/) which is not available everywhere yet (I believe it's currently in Office 2016 Desktop on Windows).